# Javascript audio with playlist

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, html5-audio

Sup, I'm using audio.js plugin in my Rails app. I know, that API of audio.js allows to make playlists, but I didn't find any documentation of it. So, how can I implement playlist with audio.js or any other js audio plugin?
There is an example of using audio.js with playlist, but I don't understand how it implemented.
http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/demos/test6.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you view the source of the page inside the script tag's at the top there is

```
<script>
      $(function() { 
        // Setup the player to autoplay the next track
        var a = audiojs.createAll({
          trackEnded: function() {
            var next = $('ol li.playing').next();
            if (!next.length) next = $('ol li').first();
            next.addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
            audio.load($('a', next).attr('data-src'));
            audio.play();
          }
        });

        // Load in the first track
        var audio = a[0];
            first = $('ol a').attr('data-src');
        $('ol li').first().addClass('playing');
        audio.load(first);

        // Load in a track on click
        $('ol li').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).addClass('playing').siblings().removeClass('playing');
          audio.load($('a', this).attr('data-src'));
          audio.play();
        });
        // Keyboard shortcuts
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
          var unicode = e.charCode ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
             // right arrow
          if (unicode == 39) {
            var next = $('li.playing').next();
            if (!next.length) next = $('ol li').first();
            next.click();
            // back arrow
          } else if (unicode == 37) {
            var prev = $('li.playing').prev();
            if (!prev.length) prev = $('ol li').last();
            prev.click();
            // spacebar
          } else if (unicode == 32) {
            audio.playPause();
          }
        })
      });
    </script>
```

As you can see it loads the URL from the data-src in the url

```
<li><a href="#" data-src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/audiojs/01-dead-wrong-intro.mp3">dead wrong intro</a></li>
```

So do something similar